# HTML5 numeric spinner element not rendering in MVC4 application

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4

stupid question time, but it's driving me nuts and I'm sure no one here will judge me. :)

I'm working on two MVC4 applications. In one,  renders the HTML5 input with numeric spinner/stepper. The other just renders a simple text box. Why?

In both cases they are generated with  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fieldname).

In the first case the rendered html is

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field # Guests:  must be a number." data-val-required="The # Guests:  field is required." id="NumGuests" name="NumGuests" type="number" value="0">
```

In the second case the rendered html is

```
<input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Columns must be a number." data-val-required="The Columns field is required." id="Columns" name="Columns" type="number" value="6">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using the same browser when looking at each?

Comment: They are both rendered as `type="number"` so the problem is not MVC.  HTML5 is still not fully supported so it will depend on the browser you are using.

Comment: Yes, I am using the same browser, Chrome, on both Windows and OSX. 
I'm more annoyed by the fact that I can't figure out why than that it isn't working.